# Spring Bean definition with value from application.yml

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, code-injection

I want to define a Bean which should be managed by Spring and having its properties being injected from application.yml.

```
application.yml //
client:
   port: 80
   address: "xyz.net"
   timeout: 100



Client.java // this class is external, we cannot change it
public class Client {
    private final int port;
    private final String address;
    public void setPortAddress(String address, int port) //
    ...
}
```

I did try using @Configuration but it's not working. The error is address is not set, while trying to access the client instance.

```
Service.java //

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="client")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=Service.class)
public class Config {
   int port;
   String address;

   @Bean
   Client getClient(){
      Client client = new Client();
      client.setPortAddress(address, port);
      return client;
   }
}
```

Any help is very thankful.

Comment: Remove the `@ConfigurationProperties` and add `@Value("${client.port}` etc. to the fields. Either something is a configuration class or a properties holder, you are trying to shoehorn both into one class.

Comment: The problem's got solved! The application.yml which wired to the test environment has missed the server property, which causes the error! application-test.yml has been referenced during the test!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't mapped the `application.yml` file to a Spring object yet.

One way to achieve this, is using `@ConfigurationProperties`. You can learn more about them here: https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

For your example, I would propose the following:

**New class to add:**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "client")
public class ClientProperties {
    
    private int port;
    private String address;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

**Autowire this as a parameter of your `getClient()` method**

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

   @Bean
   Client getClient(ClientProperties properties){
      Client client = new Client();
      client.setPortAddress(properties.getAddress(), properties.getPort());
      return client;
   }
}
```

Comment: How would you use that Bean? I've something like ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationApplictionContext(Config.class); Client client = context.getBean("client", Client.class).... It not works and show me the error, that address is not set!

Comment: Accessing beans should be done via Autowiring. 
As you can see I've added ClientProperties as a parameter in the `Config.getClient()` method. Spring will automatically inject the `ClientProperties` into that method.

You can then access the `Client` bean via autowiring as well: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

Comment: After adding the 2 suggested classes, I still got the error, that "address must not be null or empty"...

Comment: The problem's got solved! The application.yml which wired to the test environment has missed the server property, which causes the error! application-test.yml has been referenced during the test!